# Does Lotus Notes support AMQP or JMS?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, sametime

To be honest, I have no clue what these are.  I know they are some sort of messaging protocols, but that's about it.  A manager in my organization wants to know, so I'm asking.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

MJ

Comment: Do you mean the Notes client or the Domino server?

Comment: Ask that manager exactly what it is, and why he/she is asking. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMS is Java Message Service and since Domino is an application server that supports Java, you should be able to use JMS with Domino.

AMQP is Advanced Message Queuing Protocol and is a protocol that requires a MQ implementation in order to be used. If you use an implementation of AMQP that supports Java, then you can use this with Domino too.

Here's an article that shows how to create an agent that uses JMS: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-jms/

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen any reference to AMQP or JMS in either the Lotus Notes client or the Lotus Domino server (v6.5 to v9 for both)

Lotus Sametime (the chat part of the system) also doesn't seem to turn up any matches directly related to either AQMP or JMS.

Short answer, No.